# determine lower bound for $|x|^n-|y|^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose I have a function $f$ in $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)-f(y)\leq L_f|x-y|^m$, and $g(x)=C|x-y|^{s-2}(x-y)$ and $h(y) = C|x-y|^{s-2}(x-y)+\psi(y)$ where $\psi\in\mathbb{R}_+$. I need to determine a lower bound for $f(x)|g(x)|^m-f(y)|h(y)|^m$, where $m\in(0,2]$.

My approach: My idea was take $f(x)|g(x)|^m-f(y)|h(y)|^m = (f(x)-f(y))|g(x)|^m - f(y)(|h(y)|^m-|g(x)|^m)$. In this case, I need to "control" the quantity $(|h(y)|^m-|g(x)|^m)$.
So $|h(y)|^m-|g(x)|^m\leq(|h(y)|-|g(x)|)^m$ when $m\in(0,1)$. I should also analyze the case when $m\geq1$, but I don't get anything to help me.
Any idea is appreciated, thanks!